# Squat with hip pain

Tags: bodybuilding, pain, hip, quads

I have an abductor strain/inflammation and wondering what kinds of exercises I could do for my legs to continue bodybuilding. I've seen adduction strains online but I can't find any tips on abduction.  I have pain on side of hip when squatting but I can manage some weight pushing my legs out and almost squatting like a goblet squat stance where your legs are pushed out. Id like to continue working out.. any ways to treat this strain or keep working out? It's odd that externally rotating hips actually decreases pain since it's the abductor strain to being with..

What I currently do is foam roll outer thigh, glutes, stretch hamstrings and piriformis which helps but I just want to make sure I am doing the correct movement

Comment: Since we can't know what the injury is, we also can't give safe advice. For existing injuries, please consult a doctor or in-person trainer.

Comment: It literally states the injury in the post, this is the exact injury

Comment: I understand, but there's nothing exact about it. It says "strain/inflammation", so there's already a big question mark there, because they are treated differently. Secondly, inflammations are different. There are multiple types, and multiple degrees of inflammation, and they generally require different methods of treatment. Which also means that they require different modes of training IF training is recommended at all. So the only safe answer is "don't train before consulting a doctor".